# How to iterate over a Java collection which is stored as Object type?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a list of some class A defined as:

```
Object list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

I want to iterate over this. Is it possible? If yes then how? Even if I find the type of list using reflections then also I won't get to class A. 
Also, note that I don't know what class A is. I just have list.

Comment: Is this even legal?

Comment: `Object` cannot be iterated over. You would need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Comment: you cannot iterate over a type `Object`, you'll need to cast it back to a type `Iterable<T>`

Comment: what is this statement supposed to be? It surely is not close to legal java code.

Comment: `Object list = List<A> aList<>();` doesn't even compile...

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for typo.

Comment: @card yes it does compile. It gives an "unchecked cast" *warning*, but it will still compile.

Comment: @Bohemian he updated his post. Before it was `Object list = List<a> aList<>()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do so. I did something like this:

```
List<?> list1 = (List<?>) list;
```

now I can iterate as,

```
for(Object o : list1) {
// code
}
```

Comment: It's different to declaring it as an Object as you did it in your question.

Comment: I don't understand. You aren't dealing with your data as type Object. You are using a wildcard

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate an `ArrayList` the way that you've shown (you want it to be treated as `Object` - this class doesn't allow iterating, classes implementing `Iterable` interface provide this function), and then you need to iterate over its elements, you can **cast** this `list` from `Object` to `Iterable`, that way iteration becomes available for `list`:

```
    for(A a : (Iterable<A>) list) {
        // do stuff
    }
```

or when you need an Iterator iterating over elements of the `list`:

```
    Object list = new ArrayList<A> ();
    Iterator<A> it = ((Iterable<A>)list).iterator();
```

You might want to have a look at Java API Documentation of to read more about Iterable interface [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Edit: This answer was edited thanks to helpful suggestions of **Federico Peralta Schaffner** and **luk2302**.

Comment: You don't need the iterator. It's enough to cast to `Iterable`, then you could use a foreach loop: `for (A a : ((Iterable<A>)list)) { /* use a */}`

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thank you for commenting my answer. I edited it to cover what you've suggested - I guess I misunderstood OP's question a bit and thought that the iterator is needed here.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for providing this helpful link - I edited my answer to fill that gap in it.

Comment: But I don't know class A.

Comment: @RajatMishra What do you mean by saying you don't know it? You used it in your sample code in your question and so did I. You can change it to `Integer`, `String` or whatever type of `ArrayList` you need (note that primitive types like `int` or `boolean` are not allowed - you need to use wrapper classes like `Integer` or `Boolean` instead). Simply change all occurrences of `A` in the code with the name of class you need to make it work with the type you need.